# Find closest anchor point on a hexagon grid

Tags: geometry

[Image of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Y2h.jpg)

I have a hexagon grid, each hexagon is in turn made up off its own hexagon grid.
Each subgrid has a diameter of 17 tiles.

In order to keep the alignment of the top level grid, each of the subgrids share a single hexagon ring with its neighbors.
The result is a set of grids with a diameter of 15 tiles and 1 tile border.

Now each grid center is 16 tiles away from its neighboring grid centers.

I am looking for a way to calculate the closest grid center given an arbitrary point.

I'm working with Axial / Cube coordinates, but its not a requirement, if the solution is simpler in a different coordinate system.

For example, as shown in the image, the point -3,-8 is closest to the center point -8,-8.